# Forgot "git rebase --continue" and did "git commit". How to fix?

Tags: git

I was rebasing code in git, I got some merge conflicts. I resolved the conflicts and did:

```
git add
```

At this point I forgot to do:

```
git rebase --continue
```

I continued coding and did:

```
git commit
```

for the changes. Now I am on `"no branch"` and can't do:

```
git rebase --continue
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: # Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**: Look at the answer below as well to see if that's an easier solution for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12163247/493106

---

I'd have to try it out, but I think this is what I would do:

1. Tag your latest commit (or just write down its SHA1 somewhere so you don't lose it): `git tag temp`
2. `git rebase --abort`
3. Do the rebase again. You'll have to resolve the merge again. :(
4. `git rebase --continue`
5. `git cherry-pick temp`

The problem with this is that your `temp` commit probably contains both the resolution of the merge, and the new code. So it could be tricky but I would try it and see if it works.

Comment: Either you can tag like @MatrixFrog says or you can save it as a patch too. Then do the rebase abort. Check the status to make sure the repo is in a state that you know had no problems and then start the fetch and rebase.

Comment: Don't do this. See kirikaza's answer below for a much simpler/cleaner way. Don't mess with cherry-pick and resolving conflicts a second time.

Comment: @Abhilash Please accept kirikaza's answer. I (as did tandrewnichols) did this and there was a much easier way (and the internet seems to agree as that answer has 4x the upvotes).

Comment: It's now 10x the upvotes...  also, use git rerere to remember your conflict resolutions (useful, unless you sometimes make bad resolutions that you don't want it to remember).

Answer (score 251):

Just do `git reset --soft HEAD^`. It moves the HEAD pointer to its parent but keeps the work tree and adds the merge change to the index. So you can continue rebasing with `git rebase --continue` as before.

Comment: This totally worked, and was also the first time I found a use for --soft.  Nice to know how it works, thanks!

Comment: I hope people will see all the up votes on this answer and follow what is suggested here!

Comment: This is exactly what I thought (but may have passed hard by accident).  Wasn't sure if HEAD was being updated during a rebase though.  Thank you for confirming!  So glad I scrolled a bit further before messing with the headache above.

Comment: I edited the accepted answer to put a link down here- I didn't see this answer until after I followed the directions above.

Comment: Is it necessary to use the `--soft` here if I do `git add` later? I just bumped into this issue and did `git reset HEAD~` without reading this answer on stackoverflow first. Any chance I might have broken something I didn't notice?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and to make it worse, I was rebasing three commits, and after solving conflicts on the second commit, I "committed" instead of "rebase --continue".

As a result I had this [git reflog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKih1.png)

When I applied kirikaza's solution, I just reverted the third commit, and not the second one, which was problematic..

As you can see, the rebase starts by a checkout from the remotes/origin/master branch and then applies my three commits that appear as the three previous operation (before the checkout) in the reflog.

Then, if you want to restart from a clean base, before the rebase, you can simply reset hard to the hash just before the checkout of the rebase operation. In my case (see the picture):

```
git reset --hard 859ed3c
```

Then you can start a new `git rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

I had git rebased, fixed conflicts, git added file with conflicts, and (mistakenly) committed.

I tried the `git reset --soft HEAD^` and `git reset --hard` solutions given, but neither worked for me.

However, just `git rebase --abort` worked: it took me back to before the start of the rebase with a clean working tree.