# Git merge conflicts - "commit" VS "rebase --continue"

Tags: git, merge, repository, conflict

I just finished resolving some conflicts due to a pull from the remote repository of my project.

I know that once conflicts have been resolved you have, to my knowledge, 2 solutions :

- `git rebase --continue`
- `git commit -m "foobar"`

I was just wondering if there are any differences between those 2 operations, **in this context only**, as I know they are fundamentally different in their basic form ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT #2:**

If you initiated this situation with `git pull`, the expected resolution is to use `git commit`, because you are creating a new commit to represent the successful merge. If this situation was initiated with `git pull --rebase`, you would want to use `git rebase --continue` as mentioned in my original answer, as this will reuse the same commits without creating any new ones.

**Original answer (in which I assumed this was initiated with `git pull --rebase`):**

I can tell you that the recommended method is to use `git rebase --continue`. (See here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

The `git commit` method may work, but it may change your commit history if you don't use the `-C` flag, which is what resolving a `git merge` will recommend. I suppose it is also worth mentioning that the `-m` flag will change the log message, whereas the `git rebase --continue` will reuse the old commit message without asking.

**EDIT:**

Further research confirms my suspicions that the `git commit` method is dangerous and may leave your repo in an undesirable state. See here:
http://www.tigraine.at/2011/08/10/dont-commit-when-you-rebase
and here: [Forgot "git rebase --continue" and did "git commit". How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6457044/289099)

Comment: The problem is that the official Git user guide tells to commit after resolving conflicts (last sentence) : http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: That page relates to merging. Rebasing is a different operation even though it might seem similar.

Comment: Pull is fetch + merge. So my problem is related to merging, not rebasing, even if this command is used to end the merge.

Comment: So wait, did you initiate all of this with `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`? I assumed it was the latter, since you mentioned using the `git rebase --continue` command, but if you started with a `merge`, you definitely don't want to use any `rebase` commands!

Comment: I used `git pull`, but anyway `git rebase --continue` also works, which is kind of weird. That's why I posted.

Comment: During a `merge`, `git rebase --continue` should not be an option. I just simulated this sequence of events and I get an error: `No rebase in progress?` If it does somehow work for you, I would not recommend it at all. I will amend my answer.

Comment: Indeed it was just mistake I did. Thanks !

Comment: This answer could use some more detail, you say that "`git commit method` is dangerous and may leave your repo in an undesirable state", but do not explain why. it feels a bit dogmatic and it people reading it might be better convinced if they could understand why it's a bad idea to use `git commit`